# Android SDK : main.out.xml?

Tags: android-2.2-froyo

Sometimes Android SDK compiling Project will generate an empty layout XML named `main.out.xml`, which makes compile failed.

The file has to be deleted before compiling again. Why will it appear? and how to avoid it?

My IDE is Eclipse with ADT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was reported as a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=287951). There might an issue with xml plug-ins or something.  I've always deleted the `xxxx.out.xml` file. Take a look at SO threads:

1. [Eclipse - Disabling compiling of XML files while in Java perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439983/eclipse-disabling-compiling-of-xml-files-while-in-java-perspective)
2. [android sdk main.out.xml parsing error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393103/android-sdk-main-out-xml-parsing-error)

Answer (score 0):

Simply open any of the .java file in the src directory. Simply click on it an hit run

Comment: When an answer has a green check to the left of it, this answer was accepted as the solution. No need to answer unless you can add a new of solving the problem.