# Eclipse help for brand new user

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to create my first Android app. I am using Eclipse. I create a project, and before I add any code myself, I run the default project, and I get the 'Hello, MyApp' in my emulator.

All good.

I then drag and drop a button onto my 'avtivity', under the text that was added when I create the project.

Suddenly, XML errors!

```
[2012-06-02 18:03:48 - FuelLogger] res\layout\main.xml:0: error: Resource entry main is already defined.
[2012-06-02 18:03:48 - FuelLogger] res\layout\main.out.xml:0: Originally defined here.
[2012-06-02 18:03:48 - FuelLogger] D:\Android\eclipse\Workspace\res\layout\main.out.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
[2012-06-02 18:03:49 - FuelLogger] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
```

It has created a new files, main.out.xml

What's that? It's empty.

My main.xml looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If I look at the 'Graphical Layout' tab, it looks fine...

I am obviously missing something here. Hope someone can help.

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656999/error-starting-an-android-program)

Comment: try to clean your project. Menu Source > Clean up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have selected your main.xml and is oped in code window;
then you r pressing RUN button of eclipse.
Which creates error.

First of All:
DELETE : main.out.xml
From your res\layout\ folder Then

To run project:

Make open "Project Explorer"

Rigth Click on Your Project,

Click Run AS

Click Android Application

Answer (score 1):

Delete the main.xml.out file from your res/layout folder and the clean and build/run the application. If you are not able to delete the file from eclipse delete it from your workspace and the clean and build/run the application

Comment: Thanks Sir! That was part of the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Delete main.out.xml, and run as Android application after cleaning.
[Here is detailed description](http://situee.blogspot.com/2011/02/unparsed-aapt-error-mainoutxml.html)
Similar problem answers: [main-out-xml-parsing-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393103/android-sdk-main-out-xml-parsing-error)

Comment: Thanks for that! It was part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

also you might want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251658/android-sdk-main-out-xml). Seems related to your question, that main.out.xml is what's causing the trouble...